# Downloading NetCDF rainfall data from imd

Tags: python, spatial-query

I was writing a code to download rainfall data from imd, I managed to download it but it gives me the data in .grd format while I need the data in .nc format. Here is the code I wrote. Please check it and let me know what can I do to fix it. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGoMs.png)

I wanted data in .grd format but I got it in NetCDF format

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not a screenshot.

Comment: Seems to be a [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32390349) question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting GrADS (.grd) to NetCDF (.nc)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390349/converting-grads-grd-to-netcdf-nc)